# how to force an & operator for filters in search view:

Tags: search, odoo

I've a default search  *in-progress* when checking an other filter  *current_month* the operation in the search input became *in-progress **or** current_month* 
I want an **AND** operator as   *in-progress **and** current_month*

the filters are defined as :

```
<filter string="in progress" domain="[('state','=','progress')]" />
<filter string="current month" domain="[('date','&gt;=',time.strftime('%%Y-%%M-01') ) ]" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a separator between those filters:

```xml
<filter string="in progress" domain="[('state','=','progress')]" />
<separator />
<filter string="current month" domain="[('date','&gt;=',time.strftime('%%Y-%%M-01') ) ]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is sample filter using "&" that filters to display if **Assigned for the current user & with value > 1000$**

Code:

```
[[u'user_id', u'=', 1], [u'amount_total', u'>', 1000]]
```

How to get this?

The easiest way is to create a custom filter and save it in "Favourites". Then click on a ladybug and choose "Manage Filters".

[image]

Once you have this copy the code and paste into your custom module.